# JavaFX or ElectronJs for Desktop application using Bluetooth

Tags: java, electron

I need to develop a desktop app that communicates with a smartphone to send data through Bluetooth (from the smartphone to the desktop and vice versa).

I'm fluent in Java and learning JavaScript nowadays, so I considered doing it in either language.

Which framework would you choose for an application like this, JavaFX or ElectronJs?

I don't use C# and Visual Studio because I'm building the desktop app to practice any one - JavaScript or Java, but the app has to be functional beyond just being used to learn code.

Also, the app should be cross-platform between at least Windows and Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Electron has [Bluetooth capabilities](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devices#web-bluetooth-api), including for sending data. They are usable on both Linux and Windows. More info about Web Bluetooh API is in the [documentation](https://web.dev/bluetooth/).

Java and JavaScript are entirely different and it's mostly a matter of very subjective user preferences. E.g. I'd choose JavaScript anytime just because of comfort reasons as it's more modern and loose. Also note that Electron can be quite heavy in terms of using resources like RAM and it's mostly recommended for smaller projects.